# Excel Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

i m working on excel ,  i m filing the data to excel for example Excel column 1 filled up to 10 columns , later again i need to fill excel here it should start from 11th column  where the excel column is empty.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it stands, it is unclear what you are asking. To clarify it, please provide an example excel sheet in which your automation applies.

Comment: How is this related to programming? SO is a Q&A site about programming, not end user support for specific applications

Comment: Please spend few minutes structuring your question. and post the question in appropriate section

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel command in Automation Anywhere. Inside the Excel command there is an option called "Go to cell" and by clicking it you can select "Go to end of the row" again you can select "One cell below" and set the value there. it will populate values on the first empty row.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the use the excel commands

1. Open Excel spreadsheep
2. Go to specific cell
3. Drag and drop the loop command with loop 10 times
4. Set the cell Value
5. Go to one cell below
6. Continue
7. Drag and drop if command with condition with variable counter = 11
8. Go to cell below
9. Exit loop
10. End loop
    10.Set Excel value as you wish as it will be on the 11th

hope this helps you

Thanks